# Use tmux without two-step commands

Tags: terminal, tmux

On my local machine I can use the shortcut CTRL+b and then d to detach from a tmux window.
Google Cloud Platform offers to connect via SSH into virtual machines using a terminal in a browser window, see screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of menu with SSH into virtual machines option]

In this terminal, I cannot use the shortcut CTRL+b and then d to detach from a tmux window.
None of the two-step commands I tried work.
By two-step commands I mean commands that are supposed to be triggered by pressing a combination of buttons, releasing this combination of buttons, and then pressing another combination of buttons.

How can I use tmux without having to use two-step commands?

Comment: Is GCP using `tmux` *at all*? `tmux` is a program you run in a terminal emulator, not a part of a terminal emulator in general.

Comment: I installed tmux on my vm and then wrote tmux in that browser window and the usual tmux UI appeared. That's what I can say for sure, I don't know if that answers your question.

Comment: Yes, that makes it clear that you are running `tmux` in the resulting session. The only thing I can think is that the browser, or the GCP terminal, is intercepting Ctrl+b before it reaches `tmux`. Does it work if you configure `tmux` to use a different prefix?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @chepner So far, I've been unable to locate my .tmux.conf file. I'll report back once I found it.

Comment: @meuh I've tried the browsers Brave, Firefox, and Google Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

In your `.tmux.conf` file, you can set keybinds that do not use a prefix with `-n`

```
# would activate with <prefix> R
bind-key R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."
# would activate with just R
bind-key -n R source-file ~/.tmux.conf \; display-message "Config reloaded..."
```

Of course, these binds will activate whenever you hit that button, so if you used the above example, it would be very difficult to type a literal 'R'.